# Getting IndexError: string index out of range for a python problem

Tags: python

the problem I am solving is to find the sum of two large numbers, where the numbers are given as strings.
the algorithm is :

1. Reverse both strings.
2. Keep adding digits one by one from 0’th index (in reversed strings) to end of smaller string, append the sum % 10 to end of result and keep track of carry as sum / 10.
3. Finally reverse the result.

This was the code I tried:

```py
def stringadd(s1, s2):
    s1 = s1[::-1]
    s2 = s2[::-1]
    
    m = len(s1)
    n = len(s2)
    carry = 0
    s = ""
    if len(s1) > len(s2):
        temp = s2
        s2 = s1
        s1 = temp
    for i in range(m):
        su, = (ord(s1[i]) - 48) + (ord(s2[i]) - 48) + carry
        s += chr(sum % 10 + 48)
        carry = int(sum / 10)
        
    for i in range(m, n):
        sum = (ord(s2[i]) - 48) + carry
        s += chr(sum % 10 + 48)
        carry = int(sum / 10)
        i += 1
    if carry:
        s += chr(carry + 48)
    s = s[::-1]
    return s


print(stringadd("32134", "23456782"))
```

I am getting a string index out of range error in the line 17 which is

```py
sum = (ord(s1[i]) - 48) + (ord(s2[i]) - 48) + carry
```

Comment: You can try with int("32134") + int("23456782"). if the given string is not convertible to int then it raises error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- You are taking the lengths for `m` and `n` before swapping s1 and s2 around, so they do not necessarily match anymore.
- You have a `i+=1` in the for loop which doesn't do anything
- You are using `sum` as a variable name, shadowing the built-in sum function.

I would propose to rewrite it like this:

```
def stringadd(s1, s2):
    shorter, longer = (x[::-1] for x in sorted((s1, s2), key=len))
    carry = 0
    result = ""

    for i in range(len(shorter)):
        s = (ord(shorter[i]) - 48) + (ord(longer[i]) - 48) + carry
        result += chr((s % 10) + 48)
        carry = int(s / 10)

    for i in range(len(shorter), len(longer)):
        s = (ord(longer[i]) - 48) + carry
        result += chr(s % 10 + 48)
        carry = int(s / 10)

    if (carry):
        result += chr(carry + 48)

    return result[::-1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(stringadd("32134", "23456782"))
    assert(32134 + 23456782 == int(stringadd("32134", "23456782")))
    print(stringadd("999", "9"))
    assert(999 + 9 == int(stringadd("999", "9")))
```

Some of the advantages:

- More descriptive variable names
- Use `len(shorter)` or `len(longer)` instead of `n` and `m` to make it clear what is meant

You could even replace the magic constant `48` with `ord("0")` to make it clearer what that number does. And for fun, we can also use a more functional style:

```
from functools import reduce
def stringadd2(s1, s2):
    # Make s1 and s2 the same length by appending 0s to the reversed string,
    # then pair them up.
    digits = zip(s1[::-1] + "0" * (max(len(s1), len(s2)) - len(s1)),
                 s2[::-1] + "0" * (max(len(s1), len(s2)) - len(s2)))

    # The function for our reducer which has state in part and gets each pair
    # of digits in x iteratively.
    def add(part, x):
        s = (ord(x[0]) - ord("0")) + (ord(x[1]) - ord("0")) + part[1]
        return part[0] + chr((s % 10) + ord("0")), int(s / 10)

    result, carry = reduce(add, digits, ("", 0))
    if carry:
        result += chr(ord("0") + carry)

    return ''.join(result[::-1])
```

Comment: @prison-mike in case you're interested, I also added an implementation that is a bit more functional-programming style.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the code and I did get the correct answer when I send the inputs as `print(stringadd("32134","23456782"))` but when I change it to `print(stringadd("23456782", "32134"))`, I face the error. This is because you're using `m` and `n` for looping but you are interchanging `s1` and `s2` after that in some cases (when `len(s1)>len(s2)`).

You should take the value of `s1` and `s2` after the interchange. This will fix the code. Please find the correct code below.

```
def stringadd(s1,s2):
    
    s1=s1[::-1]
    s2=s2[::-1]
    
    
    carry=0
    s=""
    
    if len(s1)>len(s2):
        
        temp=s2
        s2=s1
        s1=temp
    
    # Value of m and n taken after interchaning
    m=len(s1)
    n=len(s2)
    
    for i in range(m):
        sum=(ord(s1[i])-48)+(ord(s2[i])-48) +carry
        s+=chr(sum%10 +48)
        carry=int(sum/10)
        
    for i in range(m,n):
        sum=(ord(s2[i])-48)+carry
        s+=chr(sum%10 +48)
        carry=int(sum/10)

    if(carry):
        s+=chr(carry+48)
    s=s[::-1]
    return s


print(stringadd("23456782", "32134"))
```

A couple of other things that you could change as are:-

1. Don't use  `sum`as a variable because it is a reserved keyword.
2. Remove `i += 1` from the code since it serves no purpose in the forloop.

Hope this answers your question.